# How to ask for reboot after executing Inno Setup Run section command?

Tags: windows, inno-setup

In Inno Setup there is [`NeedRestart`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents) event function to instruct Setup to prompt the user to restart the system at the end of a successful installation. Unfortunately this event is called just before executing commands from `[Run]` section (checked with e.g. Inno Setup 6.2).

My application require to setup some drivers using commands from `[Run]` section and after their execution I can check whether Windows needs reboot or not.

Is there any straightforward way to force reboot prompt after `[Run]` or not?

Comment: In comments on answer you mentioned "neither ssInstall not ssPostInstall is good for me" - it would be helpful if you update your question with _why_ these don't work for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Run your driver installation using [`Exec` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec) from `ssInstall` step ([`CurStepChanged` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=CurStepChanged)).

That happens before `NeedRestart`.

You can of course run the driver installation from `NeedRestart` itself. But that's ugly solution.